# A car is headed towards a wall, how long until the car hits the wall.

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, physics

A car is travelling towards a wall at a rate equal to its distance from the wall.

How long until the car hits the wall?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

PARTIAL SOLUTION:

Let $y$ represent the distance from the car to the wall and $t$ be the time elapsed. Then you have
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=-y$$
$$\frac{dt}{dy}=-\frac{1}{y}$$
$$t=-\int\frac{dy}{y}$$
$$t=-\ln y+C$$
$$y=e^{-t+C}$$
Since the starting distance is $100$ feet, then you can substitute $100$ for $y$ and $0$ for $t$ to find $C$:
$$100=e^{C}$$
$$C=\ln 100$$
and so
$$y=100e^{-t}$$
Can you use this to solve for the amount of time after which the distance was $10$ feet?

Comment: So to find the time it takes for the distance from the wall, or y, I have to plug them into the equation?

10=100e^-t
t=ln(10)
t=2.3

Comment: Yep, that's correct. Looks like you got it. :)

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem! If you found it helpful, don't forget to $\uparrow$! :)

Comment: Where did you get $100$ feet as the starting distance?  I don't see it in the question.

Comment: Oh... I think he may have changed the question.

Comment: The edit (removing 100 feet) makes it harder to follow the answer